# Cookies are behaving weird after saving

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am trying a to saving a countdown as a cookie. I want to make cookies of my last countdown and every time I reload it should start from last countdown. But my codes are behaving so weird. I cant figuring this out why. Here's the code snippet

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var a = document.cookie.split("=");
    number = a[1];
}
var number = setInterval(thetimer,1000);


function thetimer() {
    
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = number;
    number += 1;
    return number;
}


function alertf() {
    var x;
    if (confirm("Press any key?") == true) {
        x = "you pressed ok";
    } else{
        x = "you pressed cancel";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

function getname() {
    var x;
    var name = prompt("Lets us know your name", "Chunnu Mia");
    if(name == "") {
        x = "What dont you telling??";
    } else {
        x = name+"!!! What a uselessname hahaha!!!";  
    }
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x;
}
document.cookie = "countdown="+number+";expires=Fri, 15 oct 2022 01:00:00 UTC";
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>BOM</title>
    </head>
<body>
    
    <button onmouseover="alertf()">Dont touch me</button>
    <button onmouseover="getname()">Whats your name?</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
    <p id="demo3"></p>
    <button onclick="clearInterval(timer)">Stop</button>
    <p>01795923372</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

What should I change here??

Comment: Please, describe what do you mean - 'behaving so weird'. What you expect to see, and what you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

number is an id of interval, and a variable too?

```
window.onload = function() {
    var a = document.cookie.split("=");
    number = Math.abs(a[1]);  ///Just in case))
}
var number = 0;
var timer = setInterval(thetimer,1000);


function thetimer() {

    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = number;
    number += 1;
    ///return number; 

    document.cookie = "countdown="+number+";expires=Fri, 15 oct 2022 01:00:00 UTC";

}
```

Comment: Was that happening because cookies convert everything into string?? I'll be really grateful if you explain this to me a bit.

Comment: i think, main mistake was to set variable and interval id with a same name "number".

Comment: what about string to number convertion with Math.abs(*), i just use it everywhere, just to be sure))